# JS - Split array in to n group, each group should have random amount of key

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

I want to split this array into n groups. These group can hold different amount of key, the group can not be empty. They can hold the amount of key up to whatever. the result should vary every time. An example of expected results as follow:

splitting array into 3 groups

```
[
    ['a', 'b'],
    ['c'],
    ['e', 'f', 'g']
]
```

another example result of splitting array into 3 groups

```
[
    ['a'],
    ['b'],
    ['c', 'e', 'f', 'g']
]
```

As you can see there will be always n group (in this case 3) and the amount of key of each group varies everytime

Comment: Is there any logic behind or it's just 3 groups of `N` element where `N` is random?

Comment: Can the length of one group be 0?

Comment: @EmileBergeron 3 is example of n. So n can be 4 or 10 or 100

Comment: But we still need to know what logic is behind the number of element per group?

Comment: @EmileBergeron Each group must have at least one element. The amount of element of each group can be up to whatever. does this answer the question?

Comment: You should make that clear inside your question, and not only buried in the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a loop and the rest of the array for creating a new one in parts.

The loop generates a number and keeps at least one item to fill the last array.

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    result = [],
    pos = 0,
    count = 0,
    groupsLeft = 3;

while (--groupsLeft) {
    count = Math.floor(Math.random() * (arr.length - count - groupsLeft)) + 1;
    result.push(arr.slice(pos, pos += count));
}
result.push(arr.slice(pos, arr.length));
   
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Please, use relevant names for your variables and some comments wouldn't hurt considering this is Stack Overflow.

Comment: @EmileBergeron, is it better now?

Comment: I'll play dumb here, but is `i` really a relevant name? What's `i` in this context? It's not the index we're used to see inside a simple for loop.

Comment: i is a counter, because you want to get 3 parts.

Comment: So you're telling me that `i` is like the number of groups? Why am I not able to tell that by reading `i`? (still playing dumb by the way)

Comment: you can edit the answer, if you like, because it's SO.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
var N = 3;

var curr = 0; //current numbers added
var ans = []; //answer array
for(var x = 0; x < N-1; x++){ //go through everything but the last one
  var tmp = []; //temporary array
  var rdm =  Math.floor(Math.random()*(arr.length-curr-(N-x))+1); //random # of #'s in array
  for(var y = 0; y < rdm; y++){ //go add those random numbers
   tmp.push(arr[curr]);
    curr++; //current number being added
   }
   ans.push(tmp);
}
var tmp = []; //final temporary array
while(curr < arr.length){ //add remaining elements
  tmp.push(arr[curr]);
  curr++;
}
ans.push(tmp); //add temporary array
console.log(ans); //output
```

Since the partitions go in order, and you know how many partitions there are, you can use a random number generator to distribute them. For example, for the first array your array can contain the first M numbers, where M is from [1, 4], because you cannot have an empty list nor can you have more than you can fill the rest with just the number 1.

You repeat this random number generating for all the indexes, until you get to the last one. The last one will simply be the remaining elements.

Comment: Since this is stack overflow and the question is tagged `javascript`, you should include code that illustrate your solution.

Comment: @EmileBergeron: Not necessarily. SO isn't a code-writing service, and  because there's no code to be corrected, there's no need to write the code for the OP. Describing the solution is better, IMO.

Comment: I added a quick prototype. I find explaining more useful as well, so that they can try exploring on their own.

Comment: Okay, I did a bit of both to make everyone happy.

Comment: @EmileBergeron: Code writing service it is then. Unfortunate. Programming is about problem solving, yet StackOverflow has become the place to go to get others to solve your problems.

Comment: @squint What makes Stack Overflow great is the quick example, straight to the point. And to add to that, OP tagged his question Javascript, not Algorithm. So we can assume he wants an answer in javascript.

Comment: @EmileBergeron: No need to assume. That's exactly what the OP wanted... a free code writing service.

Comment: @squint and I'm not saying that OP has a good question for SO. And the down votes reflect that.

Comment: @EmileBergeron: Meh... I'm satisfied that the top-voted answer is incorrect. Will give OP the chance to figure out the problem when it rears its head.

Answer (score -1):

What about this solution. Here [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rb15uq3r/) as well

```
function split(array = [], N) {
  if (array.length < N || N < 0) {
    return array;
  }

  let result = [];

  if (N !== 0) {
    result.push(array.slice(0, N));
  }

  result.push([array[N]]);

  if (N !== array.length - 1) {
    result.push(array.slice(N + 1, array.length));
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: You can use code snippet directly on stack overflow instead of a fiddle.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g'];

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
var result = [];
var sum = 0;
var len = arr.length;
var left = 3; // number of groups
for (;left--;) {
  if (left > 0) {
    var pick = getRandomInt(1, len-sum-left-1);
  } else {
    pick = len-sum;
  }
  result.push(arr.splice(0, pick));
  sum+= pick;
}
console.log(result);
```